# airodump-ng station not associated with bssid

Tags: wifi, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

[image]

Why do some BSSIDs show as "not associated" (note: not all of them show as such; some just show a usual BSSID).
I have tried to use the other BSSID that shows up for the other station but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! This appears to be normal functionality; what command line options are you using for `airodump-ng`, and what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the listing is listing stations, a.k.a clients - computers and mobile phones that your chip captured either communicating with access points, or sending discovery beacons.

Your screenshot lists 4 clients, 4 of which are associated with ("connected to") `XX:AC:D2:41:22:AC`, which is the single access point you've been able to discover, while the last client (`10:08:C1:2B:7E:XX`) is not connected to anything at the moment - it either doesn't know the password for the access point, doesn't have enough signal to be able to connect to it or didn't connect to it for any other reason.

The last column, "probe", provides a hint as to why you were able to detect this station - while it isn't actively communicating with any AP, it was sending discovery beacons for a network called `hXXXX`, and your chip was able to capture that beacon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out that my wifi card which I use for monitoring does not support 5 Ghz. The "not associated" network was a 5 Ghz network that's why it didn't show up in my case.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question; those are stations and not access points that are showing as not associated.

Comment: Instead of the "not associated" text you should see the ap's mac the station is connected with. I just wanted you to consider it. Maybe it applys to your problem maybe not. In my case it was a huge insight.

And you could easily verify if it is 5 ghz or not.

Comment: If the device is not connected to a network or is probing for a network, this is normal expected behavior and not a problem.

Comment: It exist multiple reasons that's true. You may be right.